# Oracle Update Command Freezing when running it in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an update statement that works fine when I run it from SQL Developer. However, when I try to run it in C#, the program will freeze on the line that executes the command and not output anything. I have it defined as follows below:

```
private static OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
private static OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.myconstring;
cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE mytable SET PARAM1 = :param1 WHERE PARAM2 = :param2";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":param1", OracleDbType.Single)).Value = param1Val;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":param2", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = param2Val;
conn.Open();
try {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Freezes here
} catch(Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
conn.Close();
```

I have verified my values being put in are correct.

Comment: I don't speak C#. However, that sounds as if your `update` waits for a lock to be released. Check whether previous transactions (which might be *holding* those rows)  were committed (or rolled back) before running your code.

Comment: Something I would have never though about, thank you! It turns out there were in fact locks on the row.

Comment: Are you calling this function multiple times, and finding that it freezes up on the second (or later) call?